# how to add a scroll bar on videoView

Tags: android

how do I add a scroll bar video?

```
 private VideoView vv;
 vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
 vv.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled();
 vv.canSeekForward();
 vv.canSeekBackward();
```

what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: check this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37229

Comment: I do not need ScrollViews. I need a band rewind the video.

Comment: Do you mean you want media controls like timeline, backward, forward, play etc to be associated with videoview?

Comment: Add a picture of what I want

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it's called MediaController not scroll bar:) So, if you googling around MediaController maybe you will find your answer.

```
private MediaController mController;

mController = new MediaController(this) {
    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        super.show(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
        super.setMediaPlayer(player);
        this.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            ((Activity) mContext).finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

And call mController.hide() at onDestory() or when you stop video playback. I wish it helps!

[example](http://www.freemanmobile.com/2013/10/how-to-play-video-with-android-videoview.html)